# Cannot assign value to static final variable

Tags: java

I am trying to create a config file system for my game, and I want the config info from the user to be stored as public static final variables in a Config class, so all classes within the game can access the config data safely. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Config {

    private static final int n = 4;
    private static String[] values = new String[n];
    public static final String MUSIC_PATH;
    public static final String SAVE_PATH;
    public static final int WIDTH;
    public static final int HEIGHT;

    public static void ini() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {
        File f = new File("config.txt");
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(f);
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            Scanner valueGetter = new Scanner(lineScanner.nextLine());
            valueGetter.useDelimiter(": ");
            valueGetter.next();
            values[i] = valueGetter.next();
        }
        WIDTH = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
        HEIGHT = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
        SAVE_PATH = values[2];
        MUSIC_PATH = values[3];

    }

}
```

When I try to compile the code I get the error "cannot assign a value to final variable". I am able to get the code working if I remove the final, however I would prefer not to do this as they are public variables I don't want them getting messed up or anything.

I figure there is no easy way to get around this issue with the way I have currently done it, but if anyone can look at this and tell me a way to accomplish what I want then I would appreciate :)

Comment: This is one of many reasons why you don't use `public static` variables. Instead, encapsulate them and make a method to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialise `static final` fields in a `static` block.

So remove the `ini` method, and replace it with:

```
static {
   // the code that used to be in the ini method here...
}
```

Note that a `static` block cannot throw checked exceptions, so you need to handle the exception when creating a `Scanner`:

```
try {
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(f);
    // the rest of your code...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle the exception here...
    // perhaps set the fields to something default
}
```

I would also recommend making the fields private add getters for them. Also consider not having them `static` at all, and instead have a static `currentConfig` field that can be set with a public setter. It would look something like this:

```
class Config {

    private final int n = 4;
    private String[] values = new String[n];
    private final String MUSIC_PATH;
    private final String SAVE_PATH;
    private final int WIDTH;
    private final int HEIGHT;

    // getters for the private fields...

    private static Config currentConfig;

    public static Config getCurrentConfig() {
        return currentConfig;
    }

    public static void setCurrentConfig(Config currentConfig) {
        Config.currentConfig = currentConfig;
    }

    private Config(File configFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // initialise the final fields using the configFile's contents...
    }
}
```

At the start of your program you'd then do something like this:

```
Config.setCurrentConfig(new Config(new File("config.txt")));
```

Comment: I don't recommend this approach. It's hard to test, and hard to recover if something goes wrong. You're better off initializing explicitly somewhere during startup.

Comment: @Jorn I agree. If you want to be testable, I don't think you should make everything static in the first place. But I didn't want to completely deny the OP's premise of using static final fields.

Comment: @Jorn I've added a more "testable" approach.

Comment: I think I will go with the initial approach you suggested (I tried using a static block, but got an error message before so I abandonded it. tried again after your reply and got it to work), but I'm curious why the second approach is considered better. To me it just seems a lot more bloated and the method calls for the getters would slow it down (albiet negligibly)

Comment: @user21749640 Static blocks are executed whenever the class is initialised and never again. When exactly is a class initialised (though well-defined) may not be obvious and depends heavily on how you use the class. So it's awkward to test the static block. And if it throws an unchecked exception, it's hard for the client code to know where to catch it.